# Change language laravel filemanager

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how to change the [UniSharp/laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/blob/master/doc/customization.md#translations) language?

I tried:

1 - `Copy vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/lang/en` to `/resources/lang/vendor/laravel-filemanager/<YOUR LANGUAGE>/lfm.php`

2 - Change the file according your preferences

but it did not work...

Comment: Did you replace `<YOUR LANGUAGE>` with an actual language?

Comment: Yes, I tried:
cp /vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/lang/es/  /resources/lang/vendor/laravel-filemanager/

Comment: And is there now a file in `resources/lang/vendor/laravel-filemanager/es/lfm.php`? Because without `-r` in your `cp` I'll bet it said "es is a directory" and didn't do anything. And if you did `cp /vendor...` with the leading slash I'll bet it said it couldn't find `/vendor`.

Comment: You're right! I copied the directories manually, I had put the command in the comment just to show the tree of directory...

Answer (score 1):

change your local.

config/app.php
`'locale' => 'your_language',`

Answer (score 1):

After creating the directory

go to `config/app.php`

and change the entire local language for the project as follow :

`'locale' => 'your_language',`

Answer (score -1):

yourProject/vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/lang

copy your file ltm.php  language to en folder file lfm.php

Comment: Editing files in the vendor folder is never a good idea, as such files would get lost on updating the packages